# Adding an Inbound Rule in IIS [UrlRewite]

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, inbound

Currently, on my Production server, i have Inbound Rule set as follows which works file for all my requirements.

Inbound Rule is as follows.

```
Match URL section
Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
Using: Regular Expression
Pattern: (.*)
Ignore Case: checked.

Conditions section
Logical grouping: Match All.
Input: {HTTPS}
Type: Matches the Pattern
Pattern: ^OFF$
Track capture groups across conditions: unchecked.

Action section:
Action type: Redirect
Redirect URL: https://www.domainname.com/{R:0}
Append query string: checked.
Redirect Type: Permanent (301).
```

My Requirement is:
When user types

```
https://beta.domain.com it should redirect to https://www.domain.com.
```

if user types

```
http://beta.domain.com it should redirect to https://www.domain.com.
```

If user types

```
http://www.domain.com it should redirect to https://www.domain.com
```

If user types

```
http://domain.com it should redirect to https://www.domain.com
```

Thanks in advance.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't that exactly what the conditional is suppose to do?  It checks whether HTTPS is OFF and only then the redirect will happen. If HTTPS is ON it is not suppose to redirect otherwise you will end up in an endless redirect.

If you always want the hostname to be `www.domainname.com` you should add that as an additional conditional. E.g.:

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS and host name: www.domainname.com" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" negate="true" pattern="^ON$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.domainname\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domainname.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

If either `HTTPS` is **not** `ON` or `HTTP_HOST` is **not** `www.domainname.com` it will redirect. Only if both are true, it will not redirect.

Comment: Thanks Marco, I added your help!!!. But it was not satisfying my requirement. Please once check my requirement in my Main Question. I have updated the Requirement section with more clarity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it fulfills all your requirements except for your first but that's due to the nature of HTTPS. Your first requirement can only work if your SSL certificate is a wildcard certificate for `*.domainname.com` or if it's a multi domain certificate for both `www.domainname.com` and `beta.domainname.com`. If your certificate is only valid for `www.domainname.com` it will cause browsers to show a security warning when you open `https://beta.domainname.com`. There's nothing you or IIS can do about that.